# Decimal number display converter in jsf richtable

Tags: jsf

i am using jsf 1.2 / rich faces 3.3. I am displaying java 'double' type value in richtable column. the value being showed is 0.5e-4. i want to avoid this format and instead need the display in plain format i.e 0.00005 or 1.834783 and so on. how can i avoid power of e format that is displaying by default.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few ways To solve the problem :

**Create a custom converter class**

or

**changing the getter/setter** to String getDoubleAValue() and setDoubleAmt(String doubleAmt)) and parse the double to the original field (double_val).

Which ever suits you the best..